# How to fix "Only one column per table can be configured as 'Identity'. Call 'ValueGeneratedNever' ... in Ef Core and Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework-core, scaffolding

I have an Oracle Database. I tried to Scaffold my data model into my .net core 5 project using EF Core which has been done successfully, but when I try to Get a list from I get this Error:

> Only one column per table can be configured as 'Identity'. Call 'ValueGeneratedNever' for properties that should not use 'Identity'.

The table in database has just one identity column which "ID" and the other column is a simple Number without precision.
here is my model after reverse engineering:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<CreBranches>(entity =>
        {
            entity.ToTable("CRE_BRANCHES");

            entity.Property(e => e.Id).HasColumnName("ID");

            entity.Property(e => e.BranchCode)
                .HasColumnName("BRANCH_CODE")
                .HasColumnType("NUMBER")
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

            entity.Property(e => e.CreationDate)
                .HasColumnName("CREATION_DATE")
                .HasColumnType("TIMESTAMP(6)")
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();}
```

When I just make a simple select from each model, I get this error:

> The properties 'CreBranches.BranchCode', 'CreBranches.Id' are configured to use 'Identity' value generator and are mapped to the same table 'Cre_branches'. Only one column per table can be configured as 'Identity'. Call 'ValueGeneratedNever' for properties that should not use 'Identity'.

CRE_BRANCHES:

[image]

when I remove ValueGeneratedOnAdd(), it works. Does anybody know what to do?

Comment: You are mixing ValueGeneratedOnAdd with HasDefultValue

Comment: honestly, I just designed the database (database first) and then tried Ef core Scaffold-DbContext to reverse engineer the data model. This is the result of what ef core has done.

Comment: I was wondering what is Id for? Why do you need Id and Code? EF is designed for MS SQl and Id is usually the first choice for the PrimaryKey

Comment: The best place to ask questions about the Oracle EF Provider is over here: https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/categories/odp.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the problem.

The problem was I did not set default value for my numeric columns in Oracle. I set the default value of these columns to NULL and the problem been solved using the following command:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY column_name DEFAULT NULL;
```

So, after scaffolding the database, EF added .HasDefaultValueSql("NULL") to the fluent API:

```
entity.Property(e => e.ColumnName)
                .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
                .HasColumnName("Column_Name")
                .HasDefaultValueSql("NULL");
```

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

By convention, EF assumes that the column ID is an identity column. Using .ValueGeneratedOnAdd() on a numeric column also generates an identity column. A table can only have one identity column. Please check the EF documentation for column name conventions and the `ValueGeneratedOnAdd` method for more detail.

Comment: You are right, but EF added the .ValueGeneratedOnAdd() to the BranchesCode field when scaffolding finished. as I said this field is not declared as Identity.

Comment: Are you doing database first or code first? If database, first please show the definition of CRE_BRANCHES table; if code first, please show the definition of the CreBranches class.

Comment: Database first. I updated the question and added table definition.

Comment: You already know how to make it work, remove ValueGeneratedOnAdd(). It seems that your question is, why does EF add the .ValueGeneratedOnAdd() method when reverse engineering this table in an Oracle database? I don't know the answer, but perhaps if you were a bit more clear about your question, someone else might be able to help.